# Expander behaviour needs to partially expand over top content

Tags: wpf, xaml, expander

I am looking for a way to create a rollup type control, but I’m having difficulty in finding what to start with.

What I need to have two regions on the screen, with some sort of button in the lower region. When the button is clicked, this region is to expand upwards but only partially cover the upper region.

I have looked at using an Expander control, but the overridden “expansion” area can only be 100%, where as I need part of the upper panel to still be visible.
Clicking the button again should return to the previous split-view state.

I thought of looking at PopUp, but I’m convinced there has to be a better way.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Kris

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood exactly what you want, but it seems like it is something like this.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Expander Grid.Column="0" 
                    IsExpanded="False" 
                    ExpandDirection="Right">
                <ListBox 
                SelectionMode="Single" 
                Width="170" 
                VerticalContentAlignment="Top" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                BorderBrush="Black"/>
            </Expander>

            <TextBox 
            Grid.Column="1" 
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
            IsReadOnly="True" 
            BorderThickness="1" 
            Margin="0,3,3,3"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This will essentially have reduce the size of the TextBox when you Expand the Menu. When you close the Menu it will get minimized and the TextBox will be full size again.

Here is another example that I use to add a "Search box" that expands down over the TextBox.

```
<TextBox Text="Stuff" Background="Orange"></TextBox>
<Expander
                Name="searchExpander"
                IsExpanded="False"
                Grid.Column="1"
                ExpandDirection="Down"
                Margin="0,-5,20,0"
                Height="Auto" 
                Width="250" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.70*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.30*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBox
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Name="searchTxt"
                                Margin="5" 
                                Height="Auto" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center">
        </TextBox>
        <Button 
                            x:Name="SerachButton"
                            Margin="3,6,3,6"
                            Grid.Column="1" 
                            Height="Auto" 
                            Content="Search" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Grid>
</Expander>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will grow a textbox.  Will leave it to you to flop the button to decrease the TB once it is expanded.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="sbGrow" x:Key="sbGrow">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="tbGrow"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                    From="100" To="200" />
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Name="test">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />       
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Click="btnGrowTB" Content="Grow TB"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" x:Name="tbGrow" BorderBrush="AliceBlue" BorderThickness="4" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="100"/>
</Grid>

private void btnGrowTB(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Storyboard growtbStoryboard = (Storyboard)(FindResource("sbGrow"));
    growtbStoryboard.Begin();
}
```